# Density of invariant measure of stochastic differential equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I have a question: is it possible that an SDE has a "nice" density, but its invariant measure does not have a "nice" density? I asked this question at math.stackexchange but without much success, so I'm asking it here.

More precisely, consider a stochastic differential equation
$$
dX_t=b(X_t) dt + \sigma(X_t) dW_t,
$$
where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion and $b,\sigma$ are continuous smooth functions. We can further assume, if needed, that $b$ is locally (but not globally!) Lipschitz and that the Hörmander condition holds (but $\sigma$ is not uniformly elliptic). Suppose that we know that this equation has a unique strong solution and that the transition kernel has a smooth density $p_t(x,y)$ for all $t>0$, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

Assume that we know that this equation has a unique invariant measure $\pi$. **Question:** Is it true that $\pi$ has a **smooth** density $p$?

Indeed, it is immediate to see that for any measurable set $A$ one has
$$
\pi(A)=\int_A\Bigl(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} p_t(x,y) \pi(dx)\Bigr)dy,
$$
which implies that $\pi$ has a density $p$ such that
$$
p(y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} p_t(x,y) p(x)dx.
$$
However it is not clear to me why $p$ is finite everywhere or why it is differentiable everywhere. Can one construct a counter-example here?